# Recursive function seems to be fine, but won't return False

Tags: python, python-2.7, recursion, symmetric, asymmetric

So the function should check if a list is symmetric; if the list is empty or has one integer, it is symmetric.

Otherwise the function should check if the first and last integers are the same and go on recursively.  If not, return `False`.

The code seems right, but I can't figure out what's wrong and why it won't return `False`.

```
def symm(lst):

    t = len(lst)
    if t == 0 or 1:
        return True

    if t>1:
        if lst[0] == lst[-1]:
            return symm(lst[1:-2])
        else:
            return False

print symm([6,6,6,6,7])
```

Comment: Something that is really useful for troubleshooting is the [`assert`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-assert-statement) statement. It lets you test little bits of your code at once, and see if something that 'seems' to be working is 'actually' working.

Answer (score 5):

`if t == 0 or 1:` is always true since this is read as `if (t == 0) or (1):` and `1` is always going to be true.

Change to: `if t in [0,1]:` or simply `if len(lst) < 2:`

Comment: or this: `if t == 0 or t == 1:`

Comment: @NotAnAmbiTurner, yes that works too but its not as nice looking lol

Comment: @R Nar true, but more intuitive for beginners

Comment: But which one is faster?

Comment: with something this simple, the speed difference is negligible. technically, getting rid of the assignment of `t` is faster, but, again, quite negligible.

Comment: I wouldn't spend much time worrying about which one is faster as it's extremely unlikely either one of those would be a bottleneck.